# Microsoft Windows latest version subscription

Tags: windows-7, windows, subscription

I remember hearing about a subscription service that Microsoft offered to businesses where they could always have the most recent version of windows installed/deployed on their workstations (maybe even deployed from their management console). I can't remember if this was part of an IT Management package, but I'm interested but I can't recall what the product or service is named. I've Googled my heart out, but to no avail. Anyone out there know what I'm talking about?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be talking about this: http://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/licensing-options/enterprise.aspx

Comment: No, I wasn't talking about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a little more digging found it. It's called [Microsoft Software Assurance](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/software-assurance/default.aspx), which is included in Windows InTune. Software Assurance (SA) lets you have upgrade rights to the newest operating system for all the computers licensed under the subscription. Here's a good [review](http://www.networkworld.com/community/blog/revisiting-microsoft-intune-cloud-based-systems-management), or from the TechNet [Windows InTune website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/intune.aspx)

This is different from an Enterprise Software Licensing Agreement with Microsoft, because it works for any number of computers, especially if you have a small business (to which Enterprise agreements are not always given).

Having said that, Windows InTune won't deploy operating systems, but it can send updates, deploy software (both Microsoft and Non-Microsoft) via the cloud.

Comment: Updated your answer with a link to the Software Assurance page on Microsoft's Volume Licensing website.  This has all the details you'll need, if you haven't already stumbled on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Microsoft Action Pack Subscription](https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/us/pages/membership/action-pack-subscriptions.aspx) for Microsoft Partners (registered Microsoft resellers), which comes with internal use license pack for the latest versions of most popular Microsoft products. Its intended purpose is to let small companies get familiar with wide range of Microsoft products in order to help them better sell those products.